# Scope to query last year's data

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I've written a scope that returns all objects with a transfer_date from the beginning of the current year to the end of the current year.

```
scope :year, lambda { where("transfer_date BETWEEN ? AND ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_year, Time.zone.now.end_of_year) }
```

This works well and gives me the objects that I need.  But now I'm looking to write a scope that does the same thing but for the previous year.  I know there's no method in the Time class for beginning_of_last_year so I'm thinking that it might be better to define a class method instead of a scope.

If I wanted to return all objects with a date between the beginning of last year and the end of last year, what would be the best way to express this in Ruby?

I've written this as a scope but I think it can be cleaner:

```
scope :previous_year, lambda {where("transfer_date BETWEEN ? AND ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_year - 1.year, Time.zone.now.end_of_year - 1.year)}
```

Comment: BTW, instead of all this `Time.now - 1.year` clutter you can simply use `1.year.ago`.

Comment: Understood, but I need to get last year's data from Jan 1-Dec 31.  1.year.ago expresses today's date minus 1 year.  Can you elaborate on how I might clean this scope up?

Comment: I guess I could use 1.year.ago.beginning_of_year and 1.year.ago.end_of_year.  That seems to be a bit cleaner than Time.zone.now.beginning_of_year - 1.year.  Thoughts?

Comment: Yeah, that'd be better. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few optimizations I'd make here.

Since you already have ActiveSupport loaded and you're using it, make use of the `ago` method, and write something that's a little more flexible. You can also use a range and ActiveRecord can handle writing the appropriate query for your DB, no string substitution needed.

```
scope :from_year, ->(date) { where(transfer_date: date.beginning_of_year..date.end_of_year) }

# usage
Record.from_year(1.year.ago)
```

This is a lot less rigid. You can now easily query for records that are from 5 years ago without writing any new code. If you find yourself using last year in a lot of places, make it a convenience method:

```
def self.last_year
  from_year 1.year.ago
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this is much cleaner and allows me to more flexibility.  I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
(Time.zone.now - 1.year).beginning_of_year
(Time.zone.now - 1.year).end_of_year
```

Comment: This works, I updated my question with an example scope that I wrote that does this and it works.  `scope :previous_year, lambda {where("transfer_date BETWEEN ? AND ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_year - 1.year, Time.zone.now.end_of_year - 1.year)}`  Would it be better to define a class method or to stick with a scope?

Answer (score 0):

I use this line of code

`scope :last_year, lambda {where(transfer_date: 1.year.ago.all_year)}`

```
irb(main):032:0> 1.year.ago.all_year
=> Thu, 01 Jan 2015 00:00:00 UTC +00:00..Thu, 31 Dec 2015 23:59:59 UTC +00:00
```

Comment: If you want to do it for month you can use 1.month.ago.all_month